# Doctrine "has no association named"

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Add me to the list of people who can't work out what's wrong with their Doctrine mapping.  I'm modelling a Chess `Game` with OneToMany `Halfmoves` - any ideas?

DDL:

```
create table game ( game_id int primary key  ); 
create table halfmove(halfmove_id int primary key, game_id int);
```

Game.php:

```
/**
* Game
*
* @ORM\Table(name="game")
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Game  
{
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Halfmove", mappedBy="game")
 */
private $halfmoves;

public function getHalfmoves(){
    return $this->halfmoves;
}

public function setHalfmoves($halfmoves){
    $this->$halfmoves = $halfmoves;
}

public function __construct()
{
    $this->halfmoves = new ArrayCollection();
}
...
```

Halfmove.php:

```
/**
 * Halfmove
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="halfmove")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Halfmove
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="game_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $gameId;


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Game", inversedBy="halfmoves")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="game_id", referencedColumnName="game_id")
 */
private $game;

public function getGame(){
    return $this->game;
}

public function setGame($game){
    $this->game = $game;
}
...
```

Query that generates error:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em
    ->createQuery(
            'SELECT p, c FROM AppBundle:Halfmove p
        JOIN p.Game c
        WHERE c.game_id = :id'
            )->setParameter('id', 3525);
    $result =  $query->getSingleResult();
```

Error message:

> 2016-11-28 12:46:46] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 62
>   near 'c           ': Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\Halfmove has no
>   association named Game" at
>   /Users/cats/Sites/chess-ui/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php
>   line 63 {"exception":"[object]
>   (Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException(code: 0): [Semantical Error]
>   line 0, col 62 near 'c\n          ': Error: Class
>   AppBundle\Entity\Halfmove has no association named Game at
>   /Users/cats/Sites/chess-ui/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:63,
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException(code: 0): SELECT p, c FROM
>   AppBundle:Halfmove p\n            JOIN p.Game c\n            WHERE
>   c.game_id = :id at
>   /Users/cats/Sites/chess-ui/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:41)"}
>   []

Comment: Can you please show us code from where error occurred?

Comment: sorry - edit made

Comment: Both entity are in same bundle ??

Comment: c.Game should be c.game to match your property name.  That is what the error message is telling you.  And you have no primary keys defined in either entity.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `$game` in `Halfmove` entity. Try after replacing `p.Game` with `p.game`.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT p, c FROM AppBundle:Halfmove p
            JOIN p.game c
            WHERE c.game_id = :id'
        )->setParameter('id', 3525);
$result =  $query->getSingleResult();
```

**Additional Update**

Additionally i recommend some changes in you entities.

**Game.php**

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Game
*
* @ORM\Table(name="game")
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Game  
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Halfmove", mappedBy="game")
     */
    private $halfmoves;

    public function getHalfmoves(){
        return $this->halfmoves;
    }

    public function setHalfmoves($halfmoves){
        $this->$halfmoves = $halfmoves;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->halfmoves = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    ...
```

**Halfmove.php**

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Halfmove
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="halfmove")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Halfmove
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Game", inversedBy="halfmoves")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="game_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $game;

    public function getGame(){
        return $this->game;
    }

    public function setGame($game){
        $this->game = $game;
    }
    ...
```

Execute Query

```
$query = $em->getRepository("Halfmove")
    ->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->innerJoin("p.game", 'c')
    ->where("c.id = :CId")
    ->setParameter("CId", 3525);

$moves = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: the PKs in the tables are `game_id` and `halfmove_id` respectively

Comment: That would be fine. I have just suggested the entity changes.

Comment: OK, the change in capitalization in the query hasn't fixed it

Comment: I have updated answer try using `createQueryBuilder`.

Comment: using `createQueryBuilder` gives same result for me

Answer (score -1):

Try this one :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Game", inversedBy="halfmoves")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="game_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $game;
```

Change game_id to id in referencedColumnName.

Comment: but there's no column in `Game` named `id` - it's PK is `game_id`

Comment: You are not mention game_id field in Game entity.

Comment: it's in the DDL

Answer (score -1):

the problem in my case was that Mapping information was not coming from the entity Annotations at all - it was being read from the Xml mappings that were created as part of the reverse engineering (from DB) process.  Once these were deleted, the Annotations were used and everything worked as expected.